# First and last records from group by. Cannot get last

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table

```
Date        value1  value2
2012-09-07  1       1
2012-09-06  2       2
2012-09-05  3       3
2012-09-04  4       4
2012-09-03  5       5
2012-08-31  6       6
2012-08-30  7       7
2012-08-29  8       8
2012-08-28  9       9
2012-08-27  10      10
2012-08-24  11      11
2012-08-23  12      12
2012-08-22  13      13
```

values in the table is not ascending like in example. There are random numbers.

I need to get the date of the week start, `value1` on the beginning of the week and `value2` at the end of the week.

Date field is unique, and it's stores day dates only so no duplicate dates are allowed.

I tried to use the query below:

```
SELECT MIN(`Date`) as Date, 
    (SELECT `value1` ORDER BY `Date` ASC LIMIT 1) as Start, 
    (SELECT `value2` ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 1) as End
FROM table
GROUP BY YEAR(`Date`), WEEK(`Date`,7)
```

The query returns grouped weeks and `value1` correctly but `value2` is also from the row of the week start i.e.

```
2012-08-27  10      10
```

but I need:

```
2012-08-27  10      6
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you want a query to return: the start of each week, the value1 column from the row with the earliest date in that week, and the value2 column from the row with the latest date in that week.  Is that correct? If so please edit your question.  What do you want to do when a particular date has more than one different value? Average them? Take the highest or lowest?  Please keep in mind that DBMS rows do not have any inherent ordering, so asking for the "first" or "last" value is meaningless unless you put an ID column in your table.

Comment: edited a little bit. I have and ID in my table, but what should it act in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
SELECT `date`, value1 as Start, 
(SELECT value2 FROM photos WHERE t.date >= adddate(`Date`, INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(`Date`) DAY) AND  t.date <= adddate(`Date`, INTERVAL 7-DAYOFWEEK(`Date`) DAY) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) as endDate
from table t 
GROUP BY YEAR(`Date`), WEEK(`Date`,7)
```

There may be a more optimal way to do it.. but this works

Comment: Yep. Working, thanks. The performance sucks, but I need it once a week, so it will be OK while I'll found another solution. Thanks

Comment: Yeah it is going to suck if you havbe a huge table doing this method. One suggestion would be to put an index on your date field, should improvie it quite a bit